# Is there any application server available for android?

Tags: android, application-server

Is there any application server that can be used for android apps?
I have researched on GoogleAppEngine but that doesnot seem to support android though.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider using JSON as communication format and your android may happily use any server side implementation.

Comment: @Capricorn: I mean like we have IIS in windows..do we have any such application server for android apps as well?